# Remove Subtotal, Shipping & Handling and Grand Total on order email?

Tags: magento-1, transactional-mail, totals, order-email

I don't want to display Subtotal, Shipping & Handling and Grand Total on order email. How can I remove it? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Need to comment code in layout file sales.xml (\app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_TEMPLATE\layout\sales.xml)

```
<sales_email_order_items>
        <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <!--<block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>-->
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
 </sales_email_order_items>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your theme's local.xml (if you don't know how to do that, please refer to "How to use local.xml / theme.xml" in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/what-is-the-correct-way-approach-to-modify-a-magento-template/72903#72903):

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <remove name="order_totals" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

This removes the totals block from order confirmation emails.

If you want to do the same for invoice and credit memo emails, add this as well:

```
<sales_email_order_invoice_items>
    <remove name="invoice_totals" />
</sales_email_order_invoice_items>
<sales_email_order_creditmemo_items>
    <remove name="creditmemo_totals" />
</sales_email_order_creditmemo_items>
```

Comment: i need to do same for shiment email. what can i do?