# How do I remove subtotals from email confirmation email?

Tags: email

This is the content of totals.phtml:

```
<?php 
foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
        <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
        <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

I want to remove the subtotal from email confirmation but keep it in the  "Email Copy of Invoice" . How can I do that ?

Comment: the info in this similar question might help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64389/remove-subtotal-shipping-handling-and-grand-total-on-order-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a copy of the file in ...yourtheme/template/sales/order/totals.phtml and make the following modification:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
<?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
<?php else:?>
<tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
    <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
        <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
        <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),"sales_order_invoice/save/order_id")): ?> //checks for admin url
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if ($_code != 'subtotal'):?>
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif?>
    </td>
    <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
        <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
        <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),"sales_order_invoice/save/order_id")): ?> //checks for admin url
                <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total);?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if ($_code != 'subtotal'):?>
                    <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total);?>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif?>
```

Your order confirmation email will now no longer include the subtotal information.

Comment: Now I sawa that my post is not complete: It works but i want to keep in the Email Copy of Invoice .

Comment: Are you referring to an email attachment?

Comment: when i finish shopping there is an email confirmation email. Here I want to remove the subtotal. But in the admin panel from orders->invoice-> there is a checkbox with Email copy of invoice. Here I want to keep the subtotal.There are using the same subtotals.phtml file

Comment: Do you understand what i mean ? :D

Comment: Yes. I've updated my answer and I believe this is what you're looking for. Kind of a hack and slash approach, but unfortunately `Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()` isn't returning true when added the `.phtml` file. Hence the check for the `/sales_order/email/order_id` in the current URL, this validates whether or not the code is called from admin. This way, orders placed via the front-end do not contain the subtotal text in the order confirmation. But when clicking "Send Email", it will.

Comment: it do the same thing. It removes also from confirmation mail, and also from   email copy of invoice. How can I debug this ? or what other information do you need ?

Comment: I did a var dump  to the url sales_order/email/order_id and it is false. This is the url from net(firebug) /index.php/admin/sales_order_invoice/save/order_id/118/key/e094697577feea9b267226fd5fe14f5a/ ....

Comment: My mistake I thought you meant the send order button. I've updated it to reflect your var dump output. Note though that you're going to experience this with orders as well. Alternately, you'll need to specify using if / else statements depending on the URL type. I don't know why you're looking for this functionality though, but I hope your question is answered now.

Answer (score 0):

Override method `_initSubtotal()` in class `Mage_Tax_Block_Sales_Order_Tax` 
Add below code

> $parent->removeTotal('subtotal');

after code

> $parent->addTotal($totalExcl, 'subtotal');
>  
>   $parent->addTotal($totalIncl, 'subtotal_excl');

Basically you need to remove subtotal instead of adding it.

Comment: yeah I want to remove it form email confirmation but keep it in the order->invoice->email copy of invoice

Comment: can you explained with more details, I don;t get it